# Variable declaration error - Duplicate local variable

Tags: java

people, I am new to java and only started about a few weeks ago. I am trying to make a guessing game program where you have to guess the number between 1 to 100, and there is a problem.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CODE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println("Lets play a guessing game! You try to guess the number I am thinking \n");
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 to 100! ");

        String inputLine = input.nextLine();
        int line = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);

        boolean gotIt;
        gotIt = false;
        while(gotIt == false) {
            if (n < line) {
                System.out.println("Go Lower");
                String inputLine = input.nextLine();
                line = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
            }
            if (n > line) {
                System.out.println("Go Higher");
                String inputLine = input.nextLine();
                line = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
            }
            if (line == n) {
                System.out.println("You guessed my number!!!");
                gotIt = true;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

But then it gives me an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Duplicate local variable inputLine
    Duplicate local variable inputLine

    at CODE.main(CODE.java:23)
```

Any help?

Comment: Delete the `String` in `String inputLine = input.nextLine();` in the `if` branches.

Comment: Change `String inputLine` inside the while loop to just `inputLine`.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory, it means you declare a variable inputLine twice.

Once a variable is declard with `String variableName` you can't to do that again, you just need to reference the created variable with `variableName` so you overwrite the reference in memory to the new value.

Like:

```
public class CODE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(n);
    System.out.println("Lets play a guessing game! You try to guess the number I am thinking \n");
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 to 100! ");

    String inputLine = input.nextLine();
    int line = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);

    boolean gotIt;
    gotIt=false;
    while(gotIt==false) {
        if (n<line) {
            System.out.println("Go Lower");
            inputLine = input.nextLine();
            line = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
        }
        if (n>line) {
            System.out.println("Go Higher");
            inputLine = input.nextLine();
            line = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
        }
        if (line==n) {
            System.out.println("You guessed my number!!!");
            gotIt=true;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
String inputLine = input.nextLine();
```

actually does three things.  It

- creates (or "declares") a variable called `inputLine`,
- reads a line from the `Scanner` called `input`,
- assigns the line that was read to the variable `inputLine`.

That's great the first time you use it.  But later, if you repeat this line, you're actually trying to create a new variable, with the same name as an existing one.

Instead of repeating the line

```
String inputLine = input.nextLine();
```

later on, just write

```
inputLine = input.nextLine();
```

which will read a line from the `Scanner` and assign it to `inputLine`, without trying to create a brand new variable.

Comment: Thank you for your time